# How to connect to SQL database on a Windows CE Application for ARM

Tags: c++, sql-server, windows-ce, wininet, system.data

I'm trying to send queries to a SQL database from a Windows CE 7 C++ application running on an ARM architecture.

During my research I found several possibilities to do this:

- **Use methods from system.data.sqlclient**
  Doesn't work, since the application is not supporting CLR
- **Use ODBC or OLEDB**
  I read at several points that both won't work on Windows CE
- **Use HTTP requests from winInet to send the data as JSON to the DB and parse it back there**
  Just an assumption that this could work, not confirmed

So I'm wondering what other/better ways there are to send these queries.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are running WEC7 without .NET CF support and you need to access a SQL server running on another machine, am I right?

Comment: Exactly! Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a pocket pc sql server lite database then you can use [ADOCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834317.aspx) to access and configure your database. The service'esqe approach is also valid and will take the data access burden from your client application.

Comment: Thanks, ADOCE sounds interesting but I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

you can implement your third option but you need to implement also another software component (on the SQL server side) to do the following work:

- connect to the database;
- decode the JSON and query the database;
- encode the database answer in JSON and send back to your WEC7 application.

If you are familiar with C# and if you have .NET compact framework installed on your WEC7 machine you could also implement the software component that will send HTTP REQUEST in plain C# (without the need to study wininet).

Hope this helps